# Cosine interpolation between two transformation matrices?

Tags: robotic-arm, stereo-vision

Is it possible to perform cosine interpolation between two transformation matrices?

It make sense for the translation part, but how about the rotational part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

same as for the translations, you extract the 3 angles form the matrix, you have the starting angles and the target angles. Interpolate as you wish (sync-async, cos-spline-linear) and for each timestamp you can re-create the matrix (knowing the 3 angels and the 3 translations).

Advantage for cos-interpolation would be the continuity of higher order derivates (same as in the case of the interpolation for the linear axes)